# Chaining and combining RXJava calls in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java2

I have an application that uses Room to perform a load operation.

It calls the following query:

```
select * from reports r join brands b on r.brandId = b.id join models m on r.modelId = m.id join results s on s.reportId = r.id where r.id = :id
```

This returns a Single< FullReportEntity > when provided with an id

This works as intended but I have to split the calls and chain them to get the result from (potentially) different datasources.

The commands I am to use are:

```
fun getReportById(id:UUID): Single<ReportEntity>

fun getBrandById(id:UUID): Single<BrandEntity>

fun getModelById(id:UUID): Single<ModelEntity>

fun getResultsForReport(reportId:UUID) : Single<List<ReportEntity>>
```

With coroutines (after changing the above functions to suspending ones ofcource) I would probably do something like this

```
GlobalScope.launch(dispatchers.UI) {
    val report = async(dispatchers.IO) { ds.getReportById(id) }
    val brand = async(dispatchers.IO) { ds.getBrandById(report.await().id) }
    val model = async(dispatchers.IO) { ds.getModelById(report.await().id) }
    val results = async(dispatchers.IO) { ds.getResulstsForReport(report.await().id) }
    fullReport = withContext(dispatchers.CPU) {
       FullReportEntity(report.await(), brand.await(), model.await(),results.await)
    }
}
```

but I have to do the above in RxJava, which I'm still learning, so my question is how can I perform the chaining and combining in RxJava ?

Comment: [zip](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/zip.html)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `zip` function for it. It will be something like that:

```
ds.getReportById(id)
    .flatMap { report ->
        Single.zip(
            ds.getBrandById(report.id),
            ds.getModelById(report.id),
            ds.getResultsForReport(report.id),
            Function3<BrandEntity, ModelEntity, List<ReportEntity>, FullReportEntity> { brand, model, results ->
                FullReportEntity(report, brand, model, results)
            }
        ).subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
    }
```